# How to run Symfony web server at a sub-path?

Tags: php, symfony, webserver

I have a Symfony 4 web application running inside a VM.

I start the app with `bin/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000`. I have port 8000 open in the VM and an nginx proxy server running on the host.

As there are many VMs running on the host, I've set up nginx to forward requests like this:

- `https://host/project1/foo/bar` -> `http://vm1:8000/foo/bar`
- `https://host/project2/subpath` -> `http://vm2:8000/subpath`
- etc.

The problem is that Symfony does not generate the correct paths for resources or even routes because of the difference in base path (`/projectX/path` on the host proxy as opposed to `/path` on the VM local server).

My idea to bypass this is to make each sub-project in the VM run using its own custom base path (e.g. `http://vmX:8000/projectX/`). That way, I could generate correct paths, while `Router::setTrustedProxies()` takes care of URL generation.

Question is: how do I configure Symfony's embedded PHP server to run using a path prefix? I (think I) know how to do it using a web server running on the VM, but I'd prefer to avoid using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  foobar.com;


      location / {
         proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:18080;
         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }

     location /newsletter/ {
         rewrite /newsletter/(.*) /$1  break;

         proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:18081;
         proxy_set_header HOST $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
}
```

Here I have 2 apps: / -> wordpress, /newsletter <- symfony app

Symfony app runs inside a docker container.

Comment: I already made this part work. Trouble is that if I have something like a `{{ url('index') }}` (considering that `index` is the route name for `/`) in the Twig template, for instance, then the output is `http://foobar.com/` instead of `http://foobar.com/newsletter/`

That's because `127.0.0.1:18081` has no idea that it should have a `/newsletter/` path prefix. My question is, how do I let it know about the prefix without another webserver.